# It’s good to use many cookies instead of reading out the data from a mysql table multiple times?

Tags: mysql, cookies, store

I want to create a website where each registered user can customize the look of the website. E.g.: the background color, the order of items, the widgets from the sidebar, and things like these.

My plan is to save the settings in a mysql table and create cookies for each setting, so I should read the data from mysql only if the cookies are not available …

Is this a good idea or the cookies will slow down the server much more than using only mysql?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Cookies are only good for a single machine. If the user sets values while using one machine those values won't be available on any other machine.

Start the query cache and use MySQL. It will make your users happier.

Comment: Usually - but if anyone changes PC or clears the browser cache or connects from an alternate location all the cookie settings will be missing or lost. MySQL queries like this are v fast.